# Weird Instatiate health bar

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to Instantiate health bars on my units, and the problem is the health bar gets repeatedly instantiated on the first wave of units' Canvases, and the other 2 waves get empty canvases.
This script is on unit prefabs.
I am Instantiating units and health bars in separate scripts.
I can't understand what I am doing wrong here.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Example screenshot]

```
private Transform player;
private Image healthBar;
private Image barFilled;
public GameObject hpBarPrefab;

void Start()
{     
    minionExp = GetComponent<MinionExperience>();
    initialHealth = MaxHealth;
    healthBar = Instantiate(hpBarPrefab, 
    GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Canvas>().transform).GetComponent<Image>();
    barFilled = new List<Image>(healthBar.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()).Find(img => img != healthBar);
}

public void TakePlayer(Transform pl0)
{
    player = pl0;
}

public Transform GetPlayer()
{
    return player;
}

public void MinionsTakeDmg(int dmg)
{
    MaxHealth -= dmg;
    if (MaxHealth <= 0)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        MaxHealth = 0;
        if (player != null)
            player.GetComponent<Levels>().GainExp(minionExp.MaxMinionExp);
    }
    UpdateHealthBar();
}

public void UpdateHealthBar()
{
    float fa = MaxHealth / initialHealth;
    if (healthBar != null)
        healthBar.fillAmount = fa;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Canvas>()` searches the whole scene, use `FindComponentInChildren` or `transform.Find` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Simply used public Image and draged my health bar image on it, and that works fine now :)

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class RedMinionsHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float RedMaxHealth = 10;
    private float RedinitialHealth;
    private MinionExperience minionExp;
    private Transform player;
    public Image RedhealthBar;

    void Start()
    {
        minionExp = GetComponent<MinionExperience>();
        RedinitialHealth = RedMaxHealth;
    }

    public void TakePlayer(Transform pl0)
    {
        player = pl0;
    }

    public void MinionsTakeDmg(int dmg)
    {
        RedinitialHealth -= dmg;
        if (RedinitialHealth <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            RedMaxHealth = 0;
            GetComponent<BulletTieToPlayer>();
            if (player != null)
                player.GetComponent<Levels>().GainExp(minionExp.MaxMinionExp);
        }
        UpdateHealthBar();
    }

    public void UpdateHealthBar()
    {
        float fac = RedinitialHealth / RedMaxHealth;
        if (RedhealthBar != null)
            RedhealthBar.fillAmount = fac;
    }
}
```